# limit download transfer speed of nsurlconnection to prioritize others

Tags: ios

I am currently using NSURLConnection to download and upload data in my app.

Files are loaded directly to a cache.

When a user scrolls over a collection view I start downloading the relevant images (similar to pinterest homescreen).

I already have a system in place that downloads 'last requested' first, but finished the downloads that are currently running first of course.

Since I'm going to integrate download of larger files, like video or larger images than thumbnails for detail views, I was wondering whether I could limit the download speed of a connection to prioritise later requested 'large' files.

I've so far looked into `ASIHTTPRequest`, but they only allow throttling the entire connection.

I would like to avoid implementing everything on my own using CFStreams. Ant ideas?

`AFNetworking` does not offer this feature, since it builds on NSURLConnection and most other frameworks I've looked at don't offer this feature.